# Crear un nav a partir de un array en PHP?

Tags: php, array, nav

Mi profesor me pide levantar un  a partir de un array en PHP. Realmente no sé como hacerlo y queria pedirles ayuda. Si alguien es tan amable de explicarlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow en español, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información, por ejemplo ¿qué cosas ya has intentado y no han funcionado?. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas y salvar esta pregunta del cierre. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un ejemplo muy sencillo es que en tu array tengas varios datos como, titulo del link y url del link.

**PHP Y HTML**:

```
<?php
    $arrayUrls = [
        [
            'title' => 'Facebook',
            'url' => 'www.facebook.com'
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Google',
            'url' => 'www.google.com'
        ]
    ];
?>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($arrayUrls as $url)
            {
                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $url['url']; ?>"><?php echo $url['title']; ?></a></li>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Es un ejemplo muy simple, espero te sirva de referencia!